# Why is this Loop not working in qlik sense script?

Tags: loops, for-loop, qliksense

I am having a problem trying to do a FOR LOOP as it produces no values.

I am doing 3 steps, but not sure what is the problem, I have attached the APP.

```
/// 1. These are the FOR values to PASS for the variables below.

for i= -1 to -7 ;
 for j=-8 to -15;
 for z= -16 to -21

//// 2.These are variable FUNCTIONS with same structure
LET
     V_result1=(sum(Peek(Result_1,$i))*0.45+sum(Peek(Result_1,$j))*0.35+sum(Peek(Result_1,$z))*0.2)*1/5;
     V_result2=(sum(Peek(Result_2,$i))*0.45+sum(Peek(Result_2,$j))*0.35+sum(Peek(Result_2,$z))*0.2)*1/5;


//// 3. The table where to apply those VARIABLES from a RESIDENT table.
DATE_PRODUCTION_4;
LOAD 
    "Date",
    Sum($(V_result1)) as Forecast1,
    sum($(V_result2)) as Forecast2

Resident [DATE_PRODUCTION_3]
GROUP BY "Date";
```

[APP TEST](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a9ce5a1f33e474c48f9d539985b7c7d320191204174751/d8c9df)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things going wrong here:

1. If we look [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm), we see this:

> ```
> Argument      Description
> field_name    Name of the field for which the return value is required. Input value must be given as a string (for example, quoted literals).
> ```
>
> **"Input value must be given as a string (for example, quoted literals)."**

So instead of:

```
Peek(Result_1,$i)
```

You should use:

```
Peek('Result_1', $i)
```

2. If we look [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/dollar-sign-expansion-using-variable.htm), we see this:

> When using a variable for text replacement in the script or in an
>   expression, the following syntax is used:
>
> $(variablename)

So building on step one, instead of this

```
Peek('Result_1', $i)
```

You should use:

```
Peek('Result_1', $(i))
```

3. Your for loop starts at -1 and goes to -7, but in the app you added, -7 will always return NULL, since your data only consists of 4 rows. So change your for loop to a smaller range and first start of with one loop, then nest another for loop and then nest another. That way you can solve it step-by-step.